# Merge SKShapeNode and SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, merge, swift2, skshapenode, sklabelnode

I would like to merge an SKShapeNode and an SKLabeNode to make only one node

Here is my "Bloque" class who drawn an rectangle and add a sklabelnode child on it:

```
class Bloque : SKShapeNode
{
    var color : String!
    var numero : Int!
    var type : Int!

    var labelNumeroBloque : SKLabelNode!


    init(type : Int, numero : Int, tailleBloque : CGSize)
    {
        super.init()

        self.numero = numero
        self.type = type


        switch (type)
        {
            case 0: color = "#4aaddb"
            default: color = "#ccc"
        }


        var rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), size: CGSize(width: tailleBloque.width, height: tailleBloque.height))

        self.path = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(rect, 2.0, 2.0, nil)
        self.fillColor = UIColor(rgba: color)
        self.name = "\(numero)"
        self.lineWidth = 0.0
        self.zPosition = 200


        labelNumeroBloque = SKLabelNode(text: String(numero))
        labelNumeroBloque.position = CGPointMake(tailleBloque.width/2, tailleBloque.height/2)
        labelNumeroBloque.verticalAlignmentMode = .Center
        labelNumeroBloque.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Center
        labelNumeroBloque.fontName = "ArialMT"
        labelNumeroBloque.fontSize = 20
        labelNumeroBloque.name = "\(numero)"

        self.addChild(labelNumeroBloque)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

With that code, when i click on the colored space it work but if the user click on the number it doesn't work.
It seem like the the SKShapeNode and the SKlabelNode are not one entire node

[Bloque image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7edUb.jpg)

Here is the touchesBegan Function :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>)
    {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let cliqueNode = nodeAtPoint(location)

        if let bloque = cliqueNode as? Bloque
        {   // verifie que le bloque est du type Bloque
            nb++
            bloque.removeFromParent()
        }
        else
        {   // mauvais bloque cliqué    
            println("Debug : mauvais bloque")
        }   
    }
}
```

I would like to know how i can merge the both SKNode to make juste one, so when the user click on the colored zone or into the number it work.
Can someone help me ?
Sorry for my bad english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to subclass `SKLabelNode`, override `func calculateAccumulatedFrame() -> CGRect` and return zero sized `CGRect`. Label is being returned because `func nodeAtPoint(_ p: CGPoint) -> SKNode` *Returns the deepest descendant that intersects a point.* And it uses `calculateAccumulatedFrame()` to check intersections, so by returning zero sized rect it won't intersect thus returning your `SKShapeNode`.

Code might look like this:

```
class SpecialLabelNode: SKLabelNode {
    override func calculateAccumulatedFrame() -> CGRect {
        return CGRectZero
    }
}

class Bloque : SKShapeNode {
    ...
    var labelNumeroBloque : SpecialLabelNode!
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you made Bloque a subclass of SKShapeNode and SKShapeNode is a subclass of SKNode, maybe you can set ***userInteractionEnabled*** property of Bloque instance to true. Then you can write **touchesBegan touchesEnd** function directly inside class Bloque. This way you don't have to compute if the touch is inside the region. These functions will be triggered only inside the Bloque instance's region.